# What is the :link pseudo selector used for?

Tags: html, css

The `:link` pseudo selector styles elements before they are visited and `:visited` styles them after.  Is there any difference between doing:

```
a { border-color: red; }
```

and

```
a:link {border-color: red}
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Definitely difference is there. If your anchor tag does not contain any `href` values or only having `#` then the attribute `a:link` won't target the elements. Look at the snippet below, I am just using `a` and it targets all the elements.

```css
a { color:green; }
```

```html
<a href="#">link having #</a>
<a>link without href</a>
<a href="test.html">Link having some value</a>
```

Now i will try to use `a:link`, and if you look at that it will target only the element which has the `href` links.

```css
a:link { color:green; }
```

```html
<a href="#">link having #</a>
<a>link without href</a>
<a href="test.html">Link having some value</a>
```

Comment: OK - So IIUC a and a:link are essentially the same as long as the a element has an href attribute?

Answer (score -2):

a:link { color:red;}this make the link color red when it is not even used;
a:visited {color :green } this makes the link look green even if it is visited once ..